# XML namespace breaks tooltipster with XHTML

Tags: jquery, tooltipster

This jQuery tooltipster in a .XHTML file works fine

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
      xmlns:t="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" >
<head>
<title>Sandbox</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tooltipster.bundle.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tooltipster-sideTip-light.min.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="tooltipster.bundle.min.js"></script>
        <script>$(document).ready(function() {
            $('.tooltip').tooltipster({ 
                functionInit: function(instance, helper) {
                    var content = $(helper.origin).children().detach();
                    instance.content(content);              
                }
            })
        });</script>
</head>
<body>

<span class="tooltip">Hover here.
    <p>Red</p>
    <p>Green</p>
    <p>Blue</p>
</span>

</body>
</html>
```

until I add `<t:body></t:body>` inside the HTML body, after the `</span>`. The tooltip appears on hover but then won’t disappear.

That `<t:body>` should not matter. The `t:body` is in a different namespace! (It shouldn’t matter, right?)

The problem goes away if I change `t:body` to `t:bod` or if I change the file name from .xhtml to .html. (I’m using an Abyss web server.)

What is going on? How can I make this work? This app makes extensive use of namespaces in the XHTML, and namespaced elements -- like `<body>` -- that have a meaning in the HTML namespace.

Comment: This appears to be a problem with Tooltipster, now being investigated. https://github.com/iamceege/tooltipster/issues/655

Comment: This has been fixed in Tooltipster 4.1.8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a problem in Tooltipster. It has been fixed in 4.1.8.